# Why is the GUI not displayed when executing a cmdlet from powershell console, however displayed when running as a script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a following function, which displays a credential window as follows.

File: `popup.ps1` (This is not a psm. Just a script with only `popup()`)

```
function popup
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $username
    )

    $credential = Get-Credential -Username $username -Message "Provide Credentials"
    $pass = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().password
}
```

Now, if this ps1 is sourced in a PowerShell console and execute `popup()` command, the credentials pop-up is not shown. However, if I wrap this function by a calling script and execute (i.e. *right click → Run with PowerShell*) I'm able to see the GUI pop-up.

File: `wrapper.ps1`

```
. "./popup.ps1"

$uname = "viswa-ksp"
popup -username $uname
```

Could anyone explain me why GUI not shown when ran from PowerShell console, however when executed as a script? Am I missing something here?

EDIT :

It was actually a bug from my side. Fellow developer had commented the sourcing part `. <path to the cmdlet source>` as part of his debugging / troubleshooting for a different issue and I have overseen it. However thought mentally that the sourcing is still there ( since I know I had included the sourcing ).

Thanks for your valuable comments. Since more than 2 people said not reproducible, I again went and read the script once-again and found this issue.

But here is the follow-up question. I know that for cmdlet you will have to source it. But I want to understand, why nothing is happening if you just run the cmdlet without sourcing it. No error No pop-up. I even tested the return code. It is empty.

```
PS C:\Users\kspviswa\Desktop> .\popup.ps1
PS C:\Users\kspviswa\Desktop> $ret = .\popup.ps1
PS C:\Users\kspviswa\Desktop> Write-Host $ret

PS C:\Users\kspviswa\Desktop>
```

Would anybody explain this behaviour?

Comment: Random note: The parentheses around the script argument are superfluous. PowerShell commands are not invoked like .NET methods.

Comment: Hey @Joey, you are right. native c++ coder. So got carried away due to habit. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You also don't _have_ to specify the parameter name, they can just as well be used positionally. But it doesn't hurt, of course :-)

Comment: I can't reproduce with PS 4 or 5. Which version of Powershell are you using?

Comment: PS Version 4. You mean that, you are able to get the credential pop-up even if you are running as a cmdlet?

Comment: Can't reproduce. The credentials dialog shows just fine when I put the function in a file `popup.ps1` and either run the statements from `wrapper.ps1` in a PowerShell console or run `wrapper.ps1` itself. PowerShell v4, CLR version 4.0.30319.42000.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Nothing shows up when you write `. "c:\path\to\popup.ps1"; popup -username tst` in a new powershell console? Not even an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why nothing returned after running the script without dot-sourcing is , the script is not throwing any output.
save this as a script and run without dot-sourcing

```
function popup
{
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter (Mandatory=$True)]
    [string] $username
)
write-host "String Inside function"
$credential = Get-Credential -Username $username -Message "Provide   Credentials"
$credential.GetNetworkCredential().password
}
write-host "String outside Function but inside the script"
```

The output must be String outside Function but inside the script
try it by dot-sourcing

```
PS >. .\script.ps1
PS >String outside Function but inside the script
PS >popup -username USERNAME
PS >String Inside function
```

And if you don't dot-source the script, the function will get defined and removed after the script executes as the scope of the function is inside the script by default

and if you dot-source it will load function into memory.

If you change the scope of the function as global, you can use it without dot-sourcing

```
function global: popup
{
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter (Mandatory=$True)]
    [string] $username
)
write-host "String Inside function"
$credential = Get-Credential -Username $username -Message "Provide   Credentials"
$credential.GetNetworkCredential().password
}
write-host "String outside Function but inside the script"
```

You can run the script without dot sourcing
open a new PowerShell console and try this

```
PS >.\script.ps1
PS >String outside Function but inside the script
PS >popup -username USERNAME
PS >String Inside function
```

more about scopes https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx

Best regards,

kvprasoon

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't return the password because you assign it to a variable instead of actually [returning](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847760.aspx) it. Change this line:

```
$pass = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().password
```

into this:

```
$credential.GetNetworkCredential().password
```

Also, running a script doesn't automatically call any function defined in it. A function definition just makes the function available in the scope in which the script is executed. Dot-sourcing loads the script in the current scope, so you can use the function in your console after dot-sourcing the script. If you run the script it is executed in a child scope, so you'd need to explicitly call the function in the child scope to invoke its functionality. See [`about_Scopes`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) and the dot-sourcing section of [`about_Scripts`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I understand that. However my question is, what is the proof that popup.ps1 had actually executed. There should be some exit or return code set right?